# Use of 'would' for evidentiality in American English

Tags: modal-verbs, subordinate-clauses, backshifting, will-would, deontic-vs-epistemic

In American English, "would" is used more often than in British English. It seems that one reason is using 'would' for [evidential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality) use in American English. especially for indirect evidentiality and when the time frame is future.
I sometimes read news from ZDNet, and they frequently use 'would' for saying that something is not said/expected by the author, but said/expected by experts/community in the field.
for example from ZDnet [news Losing Boot Camp for Arm Macs is no great loss](https://www.zdnet.com/article/losing-boot-camp-for-arm-macs-is-no-great-loss/)

> It was almost inevitable (at least from an engineering perspective)
> that a boot loaded that could load Windows **would be** available for
> these very PC-like Macs.

So do Americans use more and more 'would' for evidentiality in comparison with British English and in comparison with for example 50's American English?

Comment: From [this Ngram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inevitable+that+he+would%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+inevitable+that+he+would%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinevitable%20that%20he%20would%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinevitable%20that%20he%20would%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cinevitable%20that%20he%20would%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinevitable%20that%20he%20would%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) if you think the phrase *inevitable that he would* is a firm indication of evidentiality, then Americans don't use it any more often.

Comment: @ Peter Shor. thanks for Ngram ( I open the link with VPN. anyway). one of the important things in linguistic analysis is frequency in general not just frequency of a firm indication.

Comment: "would" is used more often than in British English? I seriously doubt that. Comparing NGrams for *I **should / would** think / say so* doesn't suggest any significant difference  between AmE and BrE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. for indirect evidentiality you should search for frequency of non-first person subject. for example "they would"

Comment: I'm not convinced "evidentiality" is a useful concept in relation to English. The only meaningful example I see in that (caveated) Wikipedia article is *It's going to rain* (as opposed to *It will rain*), but I'm not even sure that reflects "prediction based on **evidence**". The difference between *Be careful of that dog! It **will / is going to** bite!* is at least as much about "immediacy" as "evidence". Other languages may have different verb forms reflecting *how the information in a statement comes to be known to the speaker*, but English doesn't really work like that.

Comment: ...actually, although I see no US/UK usage split, [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inevitable+that+it+should%2Cinevitable+that+it+would&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinevitable%20that%20it%20should%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinevitable%20that%20it%20would%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cinevitable%20that%20it%20should%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinevitable%20that%20it%20would%3B%2Cc0) comparing *inevitable that it **should / would*** is interesting. Both sides of the pond have *seriously* discarded dated / starchy ***should*** over the past century.